# How to calculate statistics for specific range with 2 Group Variables in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a bit of a problem.

I've got a column of data (P) that I would like to analyse (mean, standard deviation, etc.) and plot against another column (Frequency). An example of the dataset is shown below.

```
Frequency Voltage P
20000     10      0.12
20000     10      0.23
20000     10      0.51
20000     20      0.45
20000     20      0.01
20000     20      0.94  
30000     10      0.66
30000     10      0.36
30000     10      0.18
30000     20      0.05
30000     20      0.15
30000     20      0.83
```

What I am having trouble with is calculating the mean for the range of P that correspond to, say, Frequency=20000 AND Voltage=10.

Most of the examples out there use only a single group, like this:

```
by(df$P, df$Frequency, mean)
```

Is there a way to calculate it so that the dataframe becomes:

```
Frequency Voltage P(average)
20000     10      ...
20000     20      ...
30000     10      ...
30000     20      ...
```

**EDIT:**

I managed to find the mean and standard deviation for what I need:

```
df$mean<-ave(df$P, df$Voltage, df$Frequency, FUN=mean)
df$sd<-ave(df$P, df$Voltage, df$Frequency, FUN=sd)
```

But they give me repeated values. Now, is there a way of compacting all these so I just get the data frame above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `aggregate` with either `list` or `formula` notation:

```
# your data
df <- read.table(text="Frequency Voltage P
20000     10      0.12
20000     10      0.23
20000     10      0.51
20000     20      0.45
20000     20      0.01
20000     20      0.94  
30000     10      0.66
30000     10      0.36
30000     10      0.18
30000     20      0.05
30000     20      0.15
30000     20      0.83", header=TRUE)

# list notation
with(df, aggregate(P, list(Frequency=Frequency, Voltage=Voltage), FUN=mean))
#  Frequency Voltage         x
#1     20000      10 0.2866667
#2     30000      10 0.4000000
#3     20000      20 0.4666667
#4     30000      20 0.3433333

# formula notation
aggregate(P ~ Frequency + Voltage, data=df, FUN=mean)
#  Frequency Voltage         P
#1     20000      10 0.2866667
#2     30000      10 0.4000000
#3     20000      20 0.4666667
#4     30000      20 0.3433333
```

To put multiple statistics together (e.g., `mean` and `sd`), you can either cbind the results together:

```
> cbind(aggregate(P ~ Frequency + Voltage, data=df, FUN=mean),
        sd = aggregate(P ~ Frequency + Voltage, data=df, FUN=sd)$P)
  Frequency Voltage         P        sd
1     20000      10 0.2866667 0.2010804
2     30000      10 0.4000000 0.2424871
3     20000      20 0.4666667 0.4652240
4     30000      20 0.3433333 0.4244212
```

Or, you can write your own function that returns a vector of values, but then you have to do a little extra work to store the results in their own columns:

```
> myfun <- function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x))
> x <- aggregate(P ~ Frequency + Voltage, data=df, FUN=myfun)
> x[,3:4] <- x[,3]
  Frequency Voltage         P        V4
1     20000      10 0.2866667 0.2010804
2     30000      10 0.4000000 0.2424871
3     20000      20 0.4666667 0.4652240
4     30000      20 0.3433333 0.4244212
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! But is there a way of adding other statistical values using aggregate(P ~ Frequency + Voltage, data=df, FUN=mean)

Comment: @user3771106 You'll have to run `aggregate` for each statistic and `cbind` the results together.

Answer (score 3):

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Mean = mean(P), SD = sd(P)), by = list(Frequency, Voltage)]

##   Frequency Voltage      Mean        SD
##1:     20000      10 0.2866667 0.2010804
##2:     20000      20 0.4666667 0.4652240
##3:     30000      10 0.4000000 0.2424871
##4:     30000      20 0.3433333 0.4244212
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Although I can't seem to download the data.table package. I'm using RStudio.

Comment: `install.packages("data.table")`

Answer (score 3):

or

```
library(dplyr)
df%>% #?%>% chain multiple operations
group_by(Frequency,Voltage)%>% #group by variables `Frequency`, `voltage`
summarise(Mean=mean(P), SD=sd(P)) ##get the `mean` and `sd` of column `P`
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: @akrun, don't mind him. He doesn't even know R. He came here because some idiot flagged your answer as low quality, while your answer wasn't worse than any other

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution to get the values, use tapply:

```
with(df, tapply(P, list(Frequency, Voltage), mean))
             10        20
20000 0.2866667 0.4666667
30000 0.4000000 0.3433333

with(df, tapply(P, list(Frequency, Voltage), sd))
             10        20
20000 0.2010804 0.4652240
30000 0.2424871 0.4244212
```

For loop & cat command can be used to have formatted output as required:

```
for(x in unique(df$Voltage)) 
    for(y in unique(df$Frequency))  {
        cat("Voltage=",x,"; Frequency=",y,"; Mean P=");
        cat(mean(df[df$Voltage==x & df$Frequency==y,]$P))
        cat("; SD=",sd(df[df$Voltage==x & df$Frequency==y,]$P),"\n")
    }

Voltage= 10 ; Frequency= 20000 ; Mean P=0.2866667; SD= 0.2010804 
Voltage= 10 ; Frequency= 30000 ; Mean P=0.4; SD= 0.2424871 
Voltage= 20 ; Frequency= 20000 ; Mean P=0.4666667; SD= 0.465224 
Voltage= 20 ; Frequency= 30000 ; Mean P=0.3433333; SD= 0.4244212
```